# Is there a single word for the image associated with a movie?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, if we look at the image to the left of the preview on [this page](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1865505/) (the left-hand image below, from IMDB), what is the name of that image?

[image: Screenshot of IMDB]

Comment: The term is “***frame***”, see definition n.8 - http://www.dictionary.com/browse/frame

Comment: @user159691 "frame" describes any single image taken from a film, but the image on the left doesn't fit that:  it might not appear in the film itself. It's more like a poster.

Comment: In animated film, *cel* is also common.

Comment: The tooltip on the image in the IMDB page is "poster".

Comment: Agree with @Andrew. In the days before the Internet, this would have been a (printed) poster.

Comment: @Max Williams  - Yes, I was referring to the  image on the right. The one on the left is a “film/movie poster”  as noticed: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Film_poster

Comment: Or for those not on mobile: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Film_poster

Comment: would it be a lede (lead) image?

Answer (score 3):

The most usual term for an image like this is a [still](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Film_still). This is in contrast to the moving images forming the movie. Some *stills* are taken on the set and some in separate photographic (as opposed to movie) studios. The idea is to suggest that the still is taken from one of the *frames* of the movie (a moving image is actually a series of still images presented in rapid succession) though publicity photographs are rarely if ever made in this way.

In the case of an animation the still would either be taken from one animation frame or from a still image produced in the same way as the movie itself. Modern animations are computer graphics but classic animations (think Disney's Snow White) were drawn and painted, one frame at a time by an army of animators.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking this:

There is a video you can play, but you see only one frame with a triangle "play" icon on it, what is that one frame called?

If so: sometimes that is called the "poster frame" for the video.